Using FusedLocation services on wear os emulator
I'm trying to get an emulated location in my Wear Os app with FusedLocation services, but I get the following error com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Not implemented on this platform.
I'm using the regular emulator from android studio "Wear Os small round" and I connected it to my physical phone through the Wear Os app. But that didn't help. Setting the location from the "Location" doesn't work neither (it works on my phone emulator).
Is there a way to get a simulated location on Wear OS emulators?

Does the emulator have the Play Store? If not, you might not have Google's Play Services, which are needed for the fused location provider.

The emulator has it yes, but I think I need to log in an account, not sure if that helps or not. I'll try.
